# Can't visualize image in opencv. what is problem?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run ros opencv tutorial program: converting converting between ros image and opencv image using cv_bridge. but after i ran the command: rosrun opencv example input:=/camera/image_raw than rosrun image_view image_view image:=/image_converter/video_output etc, im not getting any visual output. it seems like my opencv node is running but somehow it is not converting the opencv image into ros image. im confused, but ill keep on trying by the way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236271/can%27t-visualize-image-in-opencv.-what-is-problem?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-06-07**:
Is something being published to /camera/image ? if you do `rostopic hz /image/camera` what do you get?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-07**:
I'm getting this warning:
WARNING: topic [/image/camera] does not appear to be published yet.
when i do rosnode list, it shows that my opencv node named image_converter is running, when i do rostopic list it also shows that that node is publishing the topic /image_converter/output_video.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-07**:
when i do rostopic hz /image_conerter/output_video it shows:
subscribed to [/image_converter/output_video]
but now as i done little research on my problem and done rosrun image_view image_view image:=/image_converter/output_video
i'm only getting blank window.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-06-07**:
How do you publish the images from your webcam? are you using usb_cam package?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-06-07**:
im using freenect_launch, and im subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_raw inside the image_converter node by running:
rosrun opencv example input:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
and than in another terminal when i do rostopic echo /image_converter/output_video, it displays nothing.im using kinect xbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since i was running kinect camera their was two types of image rgb and depth. that topic /camera/image_raw is just suitable for simple usb cameras. Since i was using kinect, i also had to put rgb after the camera like /camera/rgb/iamge_raw, for this i changed /camera/image_raw to /camera/rgb/image_raw inside src code and similary in CMakelList, and i get the result. he he he.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0